# Is there a piano method that uses movable Do when the students are learning tunes/pieces?

Tags: piano

Is there a piano method that uses movable Do when the students are learning tunes/pieces?

Most of the time, in my experience, teachers never really use the movable Do system when teaching new tunes/pieces. If a tune is in A major the note B is never really refered to as Re.

Comment: NNS uses a similar system, but numbers not solfege, for chords and single notes. A comment, as it's not exactly what the question asks, but related.

Comment: 'In my experience...' - what is your experience - what part of the world did you learn in? Have you had piano lessons? To what extent? For me at least, these factors give some foundation on which to build answers that will be relevant.

Comment: I have taken piano lessons in Scandinavia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always used this method  when sight reading and analyzing a piece, or when transposing it in (all) other keys to test whether I have learnt it and really understood it.

I also apply this method when reading orchestra scores, and also  when I play with the right hand a Bb-instrument - accompanying myself with the left hand on the piano.

Play and learn in moveable Do makes a lot of sense and is very benefit for beginners. When teaching keyboard in groups and in singing classes I dictated a song in movable Do and  asked the children to notate it in C, F or G major. (of course very simple tunes like e.g. the choral of Beethoven's 9th symphony.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the same thing, but years ago I helped develop a software course (for all instruments, not specifically piano) that used movable Do for developing improvisational skills.

It was called Improvisation By Degrees and it used movable Do to help students learn and think of musical phrases in different modes.

For example, if you're in A major, and the harmony has a B minor chord, you treat a B note as Re, and from there (wherever the B note is, that's Re) you can improvise up and down from that point thinking in terms of Do Re Mi and their relative intervals.

Obviously this is a sort of crutch initially, but with practice one doesn't need to think consciously and explicitly in terms of movable Do, it sort of becomes instinctive, guided by your ear rather than by an intellectual process.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know if they still use it but when I learned sight singing at Berklee College of Music a few decades ago we learned a moveable Do system. There were specific syllables for notes that were out of the major scale, for example, Mi is a major 3rd, Me (pronounced may) is a minor 3rd. I personally liked this system where Do was always the tonic regardless of the key. I find it helped develop a good ear for learning intervals.

Comment: Why should me be pronounced like "may"? Shouldn't it be pronounced like "me"? I always say "me". I would never want to sound like an Englishman in this case. Perhaps English speaking people often cannot say "me" but as a Scandinavian I can.

Comment: The word me in English is pronounced the same as the solfege note mi. The point was to have a distinction in pronunciation between different intervals.I speak fluent Spanish and me sounds different in Spanish than in English but we are discussing this in English so I am trying to answer in a way that is understood in that language.

Comment: ok I understand

Comment: The point is that every interval had its own specific pronunciation, which I thought was a great idea. Even enharmoníc notes like #4 and b5 were different. The problem with the English language is someone decided it was a good idea for vowels to have 3 or 4 different pronunciations. lol!